# How to change the color for app bar when minimize application

Tags: dart, flutter

How to change app bar color as image on flutter app?

[Color of app bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOcx7.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change this color from the `MaterialApp` class `color` property :

From docs :

> The primary color to use for the application in the operating system
>   interface.

```
MaterialApp(
    color:Colors.red
  )
```